# Почему ajax запрос возвращает 2 объекта?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

никак не могу понять, почему ajax возвращает 2 объекта.

```
<?php
if (!empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $this->inc_cnt_prds($_GET['id']);

    if (is_ajax()) {

        $basket = array();

        $basket['count'] = $this->getCountProducts();
        $basket['sum'] = $this->s_price($this->get_summa_skidki(Cart::gI()->get_cart_info()));


        echo json_encode($basket);


    }else{

        $this->redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

    }

}
```

Ответ:

```
{"count":15,"sum":"<span class=\"price\">19 830<\/span> <span class=\"currency\">\u0440\u0443\u0431<\/span>"}{"html":"","url":"https:\/\/secretno\/ishop\/add\/3608"}
```

При этом, если мы добавим `exit`, после  `echo json_encode($basket);` объект будет 1, который нам нужен.

Кто может объяснить, как это происходит?

Comment: `$count = $this->getCountProducts();$sum = $this->s_price($this->get_summa_skidki(Cart::gI()->get_cart_info()));echo json_encode(['count' => $count,'sum'=>$sum]);

Comment: Возвращает не AJAX, а Ваш сервер. Если судить по приведённому Вами ответу сервера, то можно предположить, что после приведённого Вами кода происходит дальнейшая обработка запроса и где-то в недрах происходит ещё одна сериализация JSON, которая выводит объект/массив с ключами html и url. Именно поэтому, если Вы прерываете дальнейшее выполнение с exit, то всё работает как и ожидается.

Comment: кстати покажите сам `ajax`...а то тега `php` и близко не видно ) и php файлик целеком, пожалуйста

Comment: Спасибо большое за овтеты! Действительно, если не останавливать функцию, то потом идет вызов другого скрипта php из которого и берется второй объект. xdebuger помог!